# Light web Python framework/library (file management oriented)

Tags: file-management, web-development, library, python, framework

I am creating project for a web-app for my private network to remotely manage my hard disk connected to my RaspberryPi.

I would like to make it without using the popular Django framework. I found some alternative lists ([Wikipedia one's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aPython_web_application_frameworks) and [Wiki Python one's](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks)) but I don't have the time to tests all of them.

- Python language (I just want to learn it)
- Web framework

  - HTTP support
  - Ajax/XMLHttpRequest support
  - No HTTPS or other security needs
  - No mailing needs
- Light one's (700MHz 512Mo RAM available)
- Complete file management functions provided
- Active community (regular update and good support)
- Nice to have media (common video format) management for a future extension of my project

Any solution suggestion ? (framework or combined libraries)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "file management"? Something like Finder? If you actually mean "content management", the Zope is an option.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I mean something like Finder to manage my file (copy, paste, rename, delete, comparison of metadata, concurrent access if possible, ...) without needs about accessing of the content of thoses file (but it could be nice to have, the second part of my project will be to allow video file reading).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Web.py](http://webpy.org/) is a lightweight web framework for python. There are many projects/sites that used it including [Yandex](http://yandex.ru/). It fits nearly all of your requirements like:

- It is written in Python
- It supports all your web framework requirements
- Supports file uploads, storing uploaded files, file size limits etc.
- It was quite easy and fast to prepare and serve a webpage

[Web.py Cookbook](http://webpy.org/cookbook/) have a list of *how to do*'s.